# STRIPE .NET/REACT-NATIVE: Getting an error but API call still goes through

Tags: .net, react-native, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe in my React-Native app using .NET on the server side.

My problem is that when I try to create a customer and attach a paymentMethod to it, I get a SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier: "Success", but in the Stripe dashboard the customer and paymentMethod have been created.

I need to have access to my logs so I can retrieve the customerId to attach to paymentIntents but since I'm getting this error it's like it's not going through even though it does.

```
     public static async Task<dynamic> CreateClientAsync(string email, string name, string cardNumber, int month, int year, string cvv)
    {
        var optionstoken = new TokenCreateOptions
        {
            Card = new CreditCardOptions
            {
                Number = cardNumber,
                ExpMonth = month,
                ExpYear = year,
                Cvc = cvv
            }
        };

        var servicetoken = new TokenService();
        Token stripetoken = await servicetoken.CreateAsync(optionstoken);

        var customer = new CustomerCreateOptions
        {
            Email = email,
            Name = name,
            Source = stripetoken.Id,
        };

        Console.WriteLine(" stripetoken attributes :" + stripetoken);

        var services = new CustomerService();
        var created = services.Create(customer);


        var option = new PaymentMethodCreateOptions
        {
            Type = "card",
            Card = new PaymentMethodCardCreateOptions
            {
                Number = cardNumber,
                ExpMonth = month,
                ExpYear = year,
                Cvc = cvv,
            },
        };

        var service = new PaymentMethodService();
        var result = service.Create(option);

        Console.WriteLine(" PaymentMethodService attributes :" + result);

        var options = new PaymentMethodAttachOptions
        {
            Customer = created.Id,
        };
        var method = new PaymentMethodService();
        method.Attach(
          result.Id,
          options
        );

        if (created.Id == null)
        {
            return "Failed";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Success";
        }
    }

}
```

then I call it in my controller

```
    [HttpPost("stripecustomer")]
    public async Task<dynamic> Client(Models.StripeClientModel sc) 
    {
        return await CreateStripeClient.CreateClientAsync(sc.email, sc.name, sc.cardNumber, sc.month, sc.year, sc.cvv);
    }
```

and here is my React-Native code

```
    let collection ={}
    collection.email = this.state.email,
    collection.name = this.state.name,
    collection.cardNumber = this.state.cardNumber,
    collection.month = 10,
    collection.year = 2025,
    collection.cvv = this.state.CVV
    console.warn(collection);
    
    await fetch("https://api/stripecustomer", {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
        body: JSON.stringify(collection),
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((collection) => {
            console.log('Success stripe customer created:', collection);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
```

I tried with axios as well but axios doesn't post at all to Stripe and no customer gets created.

Please let me know if you need more information!
Thanks!

Comment: can you just log the response before making it to a JSON!    like after having just the response do not do it response.json! see what is in there! it seems to be not a JSON coming from your server response when the request gets succeeded

Comment: I get [Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: response]... logging it there: 
.then((response) => console.log('response:', response), response.json())

Comment: I'm wondering if it has anything to do with my return statement in createClientAsync since it's the only place in all my code where there is "Success"...

Comment: To me it seems fetch request issue only

Comment: You're right it was, tried again with axios and now it's going through

Comment: Awesome happy that helped get in touch anytime

Comment: Well it didn't last long... Still getting the same error on different calls now that used to work perfectly fine all month... anyone has an idea of why? both fetch and axios are not working for the past couple of days...

Comment: Check your stripe account you might have used test quota limit

Comment: I just did, I haven't reached the limit yet. I'm getting this error on different calls now not stripe related which is weird because I didn't change anything and they were working fine

Comment: Your Api keys ok ?

Comment: Yes, some calls go through and some don't... same code it just makes no sense

Comment: Test those calls by mocking them in postman or insomnia

Comment: they work in local... even now the data im trying to send does end up in the database, it's just in my terminal I get Unexpected EOF

Comment: that is strange it should not be! you can check logs of each request on stripe dashboard see there